# Google Cloud Metric to monitor instance group size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I can find a graph of "Group size" in the page of the instance group. 
However, when I try to find this metric in Stackdriver, it doesn't exist.

I tried looking in the metricDescriptors API, but it doesn't seem to be there either.

Where can I find this metric?

I'm particularly interested in sending alerts when this metrics goes to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a Stackdriver Monitoring metric for this data yet. You can fetch the size using the [`instanceGroups.get` API call](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroups/get). You could create a system that polls this data and posts it back to Stackdriver Monitoring as a [custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) and then you will be able to access it from Stackdriver.